# App Stops when trying to open an activity

Tags: logging, android-intent, android-activity, zbar

I am trying to call an activity from a fragment, but the application stops when I run it in the phone. If I delete the intent, it shows the toast, but when I try to run it with the intent then it stops.

I already added the activity to the manifest.

```
package com.example.bar.adapter;

import com.example.bar.R;
import com.example.bar.zbarreader.CameraTestActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Inventory extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //inflate the right layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory, container, false);

        // Define and execute a button
        Button InvScan = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.InvScan);
        InvScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // Show a toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Openning the Barcode Reader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Call the Activity
                Intent IntentScanner = new Intent(getActivity(), CameraTestActivity.class);
                Log.i(getTag(), getTag());
                startActivity(IntentScanner);

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

Comment: also add logcat result with question. also make sure you have added CameraTestActivity Activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: show your "getTag()" method.

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the exception you get. The answer is likely in there somewhere.

Comment: What is your error ? Please post error. What is `getTag()` contains ? I think the line `Log.i(getTag(), getTag());` is throwing you an error.

Comment: the error i am getting is the followin:
android:switcher:2131230720:0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Call the Activity
 Intent IntentScanner = new Intent(getActivity(), CameraTestActivity.class);
 Log.i(getTag(), getTag()); 
 getActivity().startActivity(IntentScanner);
```

Or there must be some problem with `getTag()` in `Log`... please post your `getTag()` .

Comment: You don't have to use `getActivity().startActivity(...)`. The `Fragment` class has its own `startActivity(...)` method.

Comment: the error i am getting is the followin: android:switcher:2131230720:0

Answer (score 0):

For every new Activity you want to open, you have to write this in your **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
  </activity> 
        <activity android:name=".CameraTestActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ImageTestActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

I hope that will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

That must work:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), newActivity.class);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
    finish();
        }
    });
```

I hope that will help you :)